# Can't Scroll Back Up after horizontal scroll effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a section, then a horizontal scroll effect, but if I try to go back up to the initial section, it doesn't seem to scroll back up on my computer.

Does anyone know the problem?

HTML (initial section & horizontal scroll effect):

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".info");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
});
```

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)), url(../images/philly-map.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.animate {
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  animation: animate 2s ease-in infinite;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(3em);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(4em);
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(3em);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.info {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 4ch;
}

.content:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Learn Where</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque saepe excepturi enim laboriosam velit quibusdam? Quisquam quo maxime doloribus, placeat repudiandae animi, similique praesentium amet, nostrum quam impedit tempora dignissimos.
  </p>
  <div class="animate"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></div>
</div>

<section class="info">
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Replace</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>This</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Later</h1>
  </section>
</section>
```

If someone could put code that would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

Where you allow the scroll in certain scenarios:

**NOTE:** This seems to not work very will in the minimized snippet, so test it full screen or copy the code into you work to test easier...

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(".info");

scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {

  const scrollingDown = evt.deltaY > 0
  const isAtEnd = scrollContainer.scrollWidth <= (scrollContainer.scrollLeft + scrollContainer.offsetWidth)

  if ((scrollingDown && !isAtEnd) || (!scrollingDown && scrollContainer.scrollLeft !== 0)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
  }

})
```

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)), url(../images/philly-map.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.animate {
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  animation: animate 2s ease-in infinite;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(3em);
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(4em);
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(3em);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.info {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 4ch;
}

.content:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Learn Where</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque saepe excepturi enim laboriosam velit quibusdam? Quisquam quo maxime doloribus, placeat repudiandae animi, similique praesentium amet, nostrum quam impedit tempora dignissimos.
  </p>
  <div class="animate"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></div>
</div>

<section class="info">
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Replace</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>This</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Later</h1>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `overflow-x:` hidden; for the section, and that's why you are not seeing the overflow.

You can see it by removing it.

```css
.container {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
    ),
    url(../images/philly-map.jpeg);

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.container p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 20px;
}

.container h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.animate {
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    animation: animate 2s ease-in infinite;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(3em);
}


@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    75% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(4em);
    }

    99% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(3em);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.info {
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
    display: flex;
}
  
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
  
.content {
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 4ch;
}
  
.content:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: teal;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Learn Where</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque saepe excepturi enim laboriosam velit quibusdam? 
    Quisquam quo maxime doloribus, placeat repudiandae animi, similique praesentium amet, 
    nostrum quam impedit tempora dignissimos.
  </p>
  <div class="animate"><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></div>
</div>

<section class="info">
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Replace</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>This</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h1>Later</h1>
  </section>
</section>
```